# How can I parse CSV files on the Linux command line?

Tags: linux, unix, csv

How can I parse CSV files on the Linux command line?

To do things like:

```
csvparse -c 2,5,6 filename
```

to extract fields from columns 2, 5 and 6 from all rows.

It should be able to handle the csv file format: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180 which means **quoting fields and escaping inner quotes as appropriate**, so for an example row with 3 fields:

```
field1,"field, number ""2"", has inner quotes and a comma",field3
```

so that if I request field 2 for the row above I get:

```
field, number "2", has inner quotes and a comma
```

I appreciate that there are numerous solutions, Perl, Awk (etc.) to this problem but I would like a native bash command line tool that does not require me to invoke some other scripting environment or write any additional code(!).

Comment: Can you clarify why you don't want to use awk/Perl etc., since these tools are perfect for this ?

Comment: I don't want to write any scripts and want to use something prepackaged for the job :-) (In exactly the same way as I don't write a sort or grep tool everytime I want to use one). I realise that the functionality I'm asking for is slightly less generic that the average shell tool but would be immensely useful nonetheless - hence the question.

Comment: I would expect this kind of operation to be extremely slow in Bash. AWK or cut are the right tools for this job.

Comment: Aren't bash commands such as sort, ls, cat etc all written using c libraries? I'm not asking for a script written in bash, but a tool the equivalent of sort, uniq etc.

Comment: If you want a tool with this functionality without doing a script, you're going have to write that tool yourself. Using bash tools what you want is definitely possible though.

Comment: I had this exact same need and I documented the CSVfix solution a little bit: http://jasonswett.net/blog/sorting-csv-files-on-the-command-line-with-csvfix/

Comment: 'cut' doesn't quite cut it (ha ha) because it doesn't handle quoted strings containing delimiters, which are common in CVS files (e.g. exports from spreadsheets)

Comment: Another problem is multi-line fields in the CSV.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My FOSS CSV stream editor [CSVfix](https://bitbucket.org/neilb/csvfix/src) does exactly what you want. There is a binary installer for Windows, and a compilable version (via a makefile) for UNIX/Linux.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I want. Will download it and try to get it running.

Comment: BTW - thanks for not answering a) "why not write one yourself?" b) "use awk/perl".    If I had wanted to use either of those 2 options I wouldn't have bothered asking the question in the first place.

Comment: @Joel: The problem is the way you worded your question. You asked for a "bash command" when you should have said "standalone program". Your request has nothing at all to do with bash.

Comment: csvfix does exactly the right thing. It's a powerful csv stream editor, runs on windows & linux, and does more than what I hoped for!

Comment: Trying to download the 0.95 source for Linux and getting 'file not found'?  (The requested URL /files/csvfix_linsrc_95.tar.bz2?project=csvfix was not found on this server.)

Comment: @Jonathan The best place to  ask about problems is the CSVfix support forum at http://groups.google.com/group/csvfix - that way any problem/solution can be shared.

Comment: What an awesome tool ... thanks for sharing!

Comment: CSVFix looks like it has a lot of features, but is hard to use and missing obvious functionality like referring to columns by name instead of index (It does support this for a few commands apparently, but not all).  I'm going to keep looking.

Comment: It took me a while to find the right command, but eventually I used the [order](http://neilb.bitbucket.org/csvfix/manual/csvfix16/csvfix.html?order.html) command to accomplish this: `csvfix order -f 2,5,6 filename`

Answer (score 26):

csvtool is really good. Available in Debian / Ubuntu (`apt-get install csvtool`). Example:

```
csvtool namedcol Account,Cost input.csv > output.csv
```

See the [CSVTool manual page](http://colin.maudry.com/csvtool-manual-page/) for usage tips.

Comment: csvtool builds the whole output in memory before writing to stdout... apparently no streaming at all.

Comment: I also gave it a try. Looked quite promising in the beginning, but if your CSVs are larger than around 100MB it dies with a pretty stack overflow.

Comment: Just tried to use `csvtool`, and 5 years later (it's 2017 now) it still doesn't have streaming support and results in stack overflow for a 110MB csv file

Comment: Deprecated?? Not available in MacPorts as of June, 2020

Comment: This program is under `ocaml-csv` on CentOS (`yum install ocaml-csv`)

Answer (score 13):

As suggested by @Jonathan in a comment, there is a module for python that provides the command line tool csvfilter. It works like cut, but properly handles CSV column quoting:

```
csvfilter -f 1,3,5 in.csv > out.csv
```

If you have python (and you should), you can install it simply like this:

```
pip install csvfilter
```

More info at https://github.com/codeinthehole/csvfilter/

Answer (score 10):

I found [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/) to be useful, it is based on python *csv* module and has quite a lot of options for parsing complex csv files.

Although it seems to be a bit slow. I am getting 4MB/s (with 100% cpu) when extracting one field from a 7GB csv with 5 columns.

To extract 4th column from `file.csv`

```
csvcut -c 4 file.csv
```

Answer (score 5):

Try [crush-tools](http://code.google.com/p/crush-tools/), they are great at manipulating delimited data.
It sounds like exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

My gut reaction would be to write a script wrapper around Python's csv module (if there isn't already such a thing).

Comment: There is one: 'pip install cvsfilter'

Comment: @JonathanHartley you mean 'csvfilter'

Comment: https://github.com/codeinthehole/csvfilter

Answer (score 3):

I wrote one of these tools too (UNIX only) called [csvprintf](http://code.google.com/p/csvprintf/). It can also converts to XML in an online fashion.

Answer (score 2):

Perl script (requires Text::CSV_XS):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;
my @opt_columns;
GetOptions("column=i@" => \@opt_columns)
  or die "Failed parsing options\n";
die "Must give at least one --column\n" if int(@opt_columns) == 0;
@opt_columns = map { $_-1 } @opt_columns; # convert 1-based to 0-based

use Text::CSV_XS;
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ( { binary => 1 } );

open(my $stdin, "<-") or die "Couldn't open stdin\n";
open(my $stdout, ">-") or die "Couldn't open stdout\n";
while (my $row = $csv->getline($stdin)) {
    my @nrow = @{$row}[@opt_columns];
    $csv->print($stdout, \@nrow);
    print "\n";
}
```

Put it in a file `csvcut.pl`.

Example of taking only columns 3 and 4:

```
cat foo.csv | ./csvcut.pl --c 3 --c 4
```

This will only quote columns that need quoting, so if an input column has "Bar" (with quotes) it will come out Bar (without quotes).

Comment: This looks remarkably like a Perl script solution such as the OP said he didn't want.  (_'I appreciate that there are numerous solutions, perl, awk (etc.) to this problem but I would like a native bash command line tool that does not require me to invoke some other scripting environment or write any additional code (!).'_)

Answer (score 2):

For a super lightweight wrapper around Python's `csv` module, you could look at [pluckr](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pluckr).

Comment: `pluckr` seems to have a subset of the functionality of `csvfilter` (eg `--out-delimiter` isn't implemented).

Answer (score 1):

[`ffe`](http://ff-extractor.sourceforge.net/) is another great tool.  It requires you to create a configuration file for most non-trivial tasks.  The upside is that it's very flexible and can handle all sorts of structure, logic, and formatting that other tools can't.

I like to use `csvtool` for quick jobs and use `ffe` for complex jobs or jobs that require frequent repeating.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google reveals an [awk script](http://lorance.freeshell.org/csv/) that seems to handle csv files.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a job for awk.

You will most likely need to write your own script for your specific needs, but [this](http://www.nzgames.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-73094.html) site has some dialogue about how to go about doing this.

You could also use the cut utility to strip the fields out.

Something like:

```
cut -f 2,5,6 -d , filename
```

where the -f argument is the field you want and -d is the delimeter you want. You could then sort these results, find the unique ones, or use any other bash utility. There is a cool video [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/video/working-csv-files-command-line) about working with CSV files from the command line. Only about a minute, I'd take a look.

However, I guess you could group the cut utility with awk and not want to use it. I don't really know what exactly you mean by native bash command though, so I'll still suggest it.

Comment: I don't want to use Perl or awk. Apologies for not being specific enough in the question - I'll update it to reflect this.

Comment: This will become exponentially harder using just bash commands. You might want to check if you can use awk, because if you have bash, you most likely have awk already.

Comment: > "cut -f 2,5,6 -d , filename" - this will not work when the CSV fields contain commas and quotes, as per  http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180 which describes is much more than simply splitting on commas. Hence the -1

Comment: -1 Answer ignores preference to not use perl, awk, etc. and requirement to handle quoting.

Comment: The cut worked perfectly for my needs. So, there goes a +1 :)

Comment: @user359996 That bit wasn't in the question when I submitted this answer.

Comment: Fair enough; would remove downvote if I could, but please consider deleting this answer as now irrelevant.