# Simplest scripting language for working with CSVs

Tags: scripting, csv

I like using Python, because of the easy-to-learn syntax, however, I recently learned it has no support for UTF-8 in the area of CSVs. As I often use CSVs, this seems a serious problem for me. Is there another scripting language that has a simple syntax that I can learn when I need to manage really large CSV UTF-8 files?

Comment: wouldn't be better to ask if there is a utf-8 / unicode supporting version of the csv module?

Comment: Is there a UTF-8 supporting version of the CSV module? I read the documentation and it says no. Also, I tried some code myself (in Python 2.6.6) and my Chinese characters became a bunch of short strings of letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using `gawk`. E.g.:

```
awk -F ";" '{print $1 ";" $2}' FILE.csv
```

would print `FILE.CSV`'s first two (`;` separated) column. To work properly with UTF-8, you should use it like:

LC_ALL=C awk 'BEGIN {print length("árvíztűrőtükörkúrópék")}'
   => 30
   LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 awk 'BEGIN {print length("árvíztűrőtükörkúrópék")}'
   => 21

(Or you can set LC_ALL globally if you're using UTF-8 all the time, and you're on *nix, e.g. in `.bashrc`, `export LC_ALL=en_US.utf8`.)

`awk` is an old, but really powerful and fast tool.

HTH

Comment: Will this solution handle csv files that encode the delimiter?

Comment: Like this: https://ideone.com/bLPPf ? (Note, I did not set the `OFS` so it's space by default.)

Comment: Not quite. I meant encode the delimiter in the strings being separated e.g. 'a,b,"c,d",e' is a csv encoded string with 4 columns (the third being the string 'c,d')

Comment: Oh, that's a good question. It can be done, but that requires more effort. E.g. First I'd encode all the fields to be `"` encoded, then replece all `","` with some other delimiter, then use the other delimiter. (I know that sometimes it's not enough.

Comment: Yes, It get's complicated. I'd recommend a tool that already handles this, rather than building your own. There are other edge cases too, such as multi-line records and escaping the field quoting character.

Comment: Couldn't agree more on reusing existing tools.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working on the command and can install another command line tool I'd strongly recommend [csvfix](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/).

Once installed you can robustly query any csv file e.g.

```
csvfix order -f 1,3 file.csv
```

will extract the 1st and 3rd columns of a csv.

There is a full list of commands [here](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/wiki/Commands)

See this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063125/linux-tool-to-parse-csv-files)