# Is there a tool or using php to get it?

Tags: php, csv

Update some columns content in some **csv** files with a batch.

eg: `1.csv 2.csv  3.csv 4.csv.....`

All the columns name are the same in all the csv file.

Suppposed those `csv` files have columns `test1  test2  test3  test4 test5......` . the test1 have contents like this:

```
0
0
0
0 
..
```

now, i want to change them to `99`, namely:

```
99
99
99
99
..
```

Is  there a tool or using php to update  the content in all the csv files synchronously and update the content with a batch. thank you

Comment: There are many ways to do this, Really though you have not given enough information. Do you use windows or linux, as you can use simple shell commands in linux that you can't in windows. Do you only want to replace out some instances of some values in some columns or all values of x in just one column or all values of x anywhere etc.

Comment: i am using windows and replace  all values of x in just one column

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux Tool To Parse CSV files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063125/linux-tool-to-parse-csv-files)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), and [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

Comment: i have too many csv files. eg:20 how using fgetcsv() open them and output the result?

Comment: @run: Please learn how to use that function first. Otherwise hire a developer, you can not expect others here to write a PHP script for you.

Answer (score 0):

On windows there is no such tool to do that in batches automatically. You can however open all such files inside a spreadsheet application and quickly change them.

If the number of files is too much, you can pick the scripting language of your choice (PHP) and write some file processing routines that deal with the data and the change of it. The PHP manual leads you the way to multiple functions you can use, and so did NADH.

I hope this anwers your question.

Comment: because, the files is too many, so update them will cost me lots of time. i have installed centos system on my vmware. could you give me some tips if i using linux to get that? many thanks

Comment: @run: Please use the search, it's rather trivial as the information is already available.