# Count number of column in a pipe delimited file

Tags: linux, perl, shell, awk

I have a pipe `|` delimited file.

**File:**

```
106232145|"medicare"|"medicare,medicaid"|789
```

I would like to count the number of fields in each line. I tried the below code

**Code:**

```
awk -F '|' '{print NF-1}'
```

This returns me the result as 5 instead of 4. This is because the awk takes "medicare|medicaid" as two different fields instead of one field

Comment: The only way I can think of that you got 5 instead of 4 with that command is if you actually did `awk -F\" ...` (or instead of the double quote, one of the other characters that occurs 4 times in the string, like `d` or `i`...). In fact, with `NF-1`, you should have gotten 3 instead...

Comment: But your example does not contain "medicare|medicaid" ??

Comment: If you have data that can contain the delimiter in quoted field values, then you need a specialized CSV-style parser.  The chances are [`csvfix`](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/) can do what you need.  See also [Linux tool to parse CSV files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063125/linux-tool-to-parse-csv-files).  There are Perl modules to help; it is likely that Python and Ruby have modules to help too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
awk -F\| '{print NF}'
```

gives correct result.

Comment: -1 - this breaks when the file contains pipes as part of the field (e.g. "medicare|medicaid") which is valid in generic delimited files.

Answer (score 5):

Pure Unix solution (without awk/Perl):

```
$ cat  /tmp/x1
1|2|3|34
4534|23442|1121|334434

$ head -1 /tmp/x1 | tr "|" "\012" | wc -l
4
```

Perl solution - 1-liner:

```
$ perl5.8 -naF'\|' -e 'print scalar(@F)."\n";exit;' /tmp/x1
4
```

---

**BUT!!!! IMPORTANT!!!**

**Every one of these solutions - as well as those on other answers - do NOT work 100%!**

Namely, **they all break when it's a REAL "pipe-separated" file, with a pipe being a valid character in the field (and the field being quoted)**, the way real CSV files work.

E.g.

```
$ cat /tmp/x2
"0|1"|2|3|34
4534|23442|1121|334434
$ perl5.8 -naF'\|' -e 'print scalar(@F)."\n";exit;' /tmp/x1
5   <----- BROKEN!!! There are only 4 fields, first field is "0|1"
```

To fix that, **a proper CSV (or delimited file) parser should be used**, such as one in Perl:

```
$ perl5.8 -MText::CSV_XS 
-ne '$csv=Text::CSV_XS->new({sep_char => "|"});  $csv->parse($_); 
print $csv->fields(); print "\n"; exit;' /tmp/x2
```

Prints correct value

```
4
```

As a note, simply fixing an `awk` or `sed` solution with a convoluted RegEx won't work easily, since on top of pipe-containing-and-quoted PSV fields, the spec also allows *quotes* as part of the field as well. That does NOT lend itself to a nice RegEx solution.

Comment: `tr`, `head` and `wc` are no more "pure unix" than `awk`... `perl` is a slightly different story...

Comment: @twalberg - some legacy stripped down unixes may come without awk or Perl. Or Windows systems with Unix util packages installed

Comment: Can't disagree on `perl`, but `awk` is part of SUS, LSB and other similar standards. Sure, someone could intentionally choose not to install some of the core packages, but that doesn't make their installation any more "pure" (and in fact, may make it more "broken")...

Comment: @twalberg - the fact that you use the word "core packages" means you are NOT talking about unixes older/odder than those with package managers.

Comment: On the contrary, I meant "packages" in a much more generic sense - whether it's an RPM, or a `tar` archive or a `shar` or `uuencoded` file, it's still a "package" in the generic sense. And while I may have never worked on a PDP-11, I do at least remember installing SunOS 2.5 from floppies, and learning C on an AT&T SVR2 system...

Comment: @twalberg - Just asked on Unix.SE. Apparently, BusyBox's default install excludes `awk`

Comment: Awk appeared in [V7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_7_Unix) and was always in BSD, so you'd be hard pressed to find a historical Unix without it that's still running. All distributions of Unix tools for non-Unix operating systems include it. The only systems that might be called Unix and be used in practice today that don't have awk are embedded systems (likely running [Busybox](http://www.busybox.net/)), and they would be described as running a *stripped-down Unix*. Perl, on the other hand, is typically absent from embedded Unices, isn't in MINIX3 or the default NetBSD install.

Comment: @Gilles - fully agree about Perl. The discussion was about the very first solution, that I called "pure Unix" for not using `awk` NOR `perl`. The reason I didn't supply an `awk` solution is because it was already present in another answer, not out of some deep `awk` hatred :)

Comment: @DVK A “pure unix” solution can use awk. If someone tells you they're running “Unix” or “Linux”, you can safely assume they have awk (and Perl is likely too but not absolutely guaranteed). If they tell you that they're running “a stripped-down unix” (or synonyms thereof), you're right to worry about awk.

Comment: @Gilles - another benefit of not relying on `awk` - systems like mine which are Windows boxen with a package of Unix commands installed (NOT cygwin), but no Strawberry Perl. AFAIR, those packages include tr/head/etc... but NOT awk. Mind you, you won't call them "Unix", I suppose :) Anyway, if this was on Politics SE, this whole comment thread would have been nuked by Yannis already, as it is totally irrelevant to the question OR the answer itself :). And I don't see a "lets take this to chat" link for some reason.

Comment: @DVK A Unix utility distribution without awk, really? Msys, GNUwin32, DJGPP, Git bash all have awk. Any set of POSIX utilities obviously has awk.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33167/discussion-between-dvk-and-gilles)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat fieldparse.awk
#NR > 1 { print "--"; }

# Uncomment printf/print in the for loops to see
#   each field on a separate line as well as the commented line above (to show that it works).
{
    nfields = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ /^".*[^"]$/)
            for (; i <= NF && ($i !~ /.*"$/); i++) {
                #printf("%s%s", $i, FS);
            }
        #print $i;
        nfields++;
    }
    print nfields;
    if (FILENAME == "-")
        FILENAME = "(standard input)";
    filenames[FILENAME] = sprintf("%d %d", FNR, nfields);
}

END {
    print NR, "total records processed";
    for (f in filenames) {
        split(filenames[f], fn, " ");
        printf("\t* %s: %d records with %d fields\n", f, fn[1], fn[2]);
    }
}

$ awk -F'|' -f fieldparse.awk demo.txt
```

It works for any single character separator that is NOT a double quotation mark, meaning standard tab delimited, CSV, etc. formats (as standard as they get anyway...)

The output format is merely illustrative and a bit decorative at the end, but the content is still useful IMHO, such as handling multiple files. In any case, I hope it helps! :-)

**Edit**

This was tested using mawk and GNU awk (gawk), the latter of which was tested in traditional, POSIX and the default modes. Trim the comments and output statements to find it actually a small program, though it isn't as small as one might like.

Answer (score 0):

For a `|` delimited file with embedded `|` in between this `GNU awk v4.0` or later should work:

```
gawk '{ print NF }' FPAT="([^|]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
```

Comment: -1 - this breaks when the file contains pipes as part of the field (e.g. "medicare|medicaid") which is valid in generic delimited files.

Comment: @DVK Sorry good point. I have updated the solution for lines with embedded pipes.

Comment: Now, try to update it to account for double quotes being part of the field text, which your updated version doesn't work on) (possible with a RegEx, may be. But PAINFUL!)

Comment: @DVK You are absolutely right. Parsing a csv (though pipe delimited) with `awk` is like parsing xml. Will break at some odd edge case.

Answer (score -1):

`perl -ne 'print scalar( split( /\|/, $_ ) ) . "\n"'` *[filename]*