# I want a command to replace extra commas in a comma delimited csv file

Tags: bash, csv, unix, awk, sed

I have below records in comma delimited csv file all fields values are under quotes(“”)

Sample record 1:

```
“1234”,”0”,”1”,2012-12-01 11:38:00”,”Dear ABC thank you for ,your, email.
If you have any further query please contact us.

Thanks & Regards,

John

Services abc company”,”Null”,”1”,”John”
```

Sample record 2:

```
“789”,”0”,”1”,2012-09-01 11:38:00”,”Dear XYZ thank you for “your”, email.
If you have any further query please contact us.

Thanks & Regards,

Max

Services department abc company”,”Null”,”1”,”Max”
```

Note: please help me with sed/awk commands or unix script using read line.

Solution i have tried:

```
sed -e ‘s/\([^”]\)”,\([^”]\)/\1~\2/g’ -e ‘s/\([^”]\),\([^”]\)/\1~\2/g’ file.csv
```

In the first part of `sed` I am removing text with the below pattern from record 2:  *your”,

And in the second part, I am removing the extra comma in between normal text from record 1 :
`,your,`

Expectations: Remove all extra commas from records as below:

Output record 1:

```
“1234”,”0”,”1”,2012-12-01 11:38:00”,”Dear ABC thank you for your email.
If you have any further query please contact us.

Thanks & Regards

John
Services abc company”,”Null”,”1”,”John”
```

Output record 2:

```
“789”,”0”,”1”,2012-09-01 11:38:00”,”Dear XYZ thank you for “your” email.
If you have any further query please contact us.

Thanks & Regards

Max

Services department abc company”,”Null”,”1”,”Max”
```

Comment: Please [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) the code/csv in your question. Currently, it is hard to read and we are not sure where the newlines are.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063125/how-can-i-parse-csv-files-on-the-linux-command-line

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If your downstream processing cannot handle valid CSV with quoted commas, you want to fix that instead. (Also, the curly quotes in your question are not really valid quotes in CSV.)

Comment: It looks to me the left quote `“` and the right quote `”` are used in an odd way.
For instance, while `“1234”` looks good, `”0”` has the right quotes on the both ends.
Besides the field `2012-12-01 11:38:00”` lacks the beginning quote.
If you can correct these incoherency, we could offer a better solution. BR.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/ ,?(“?[[:alnum:]]+”?),? / \1 /g' file.csv
“1234”,”0”,”1”2012-12-01 11:38:00”,”Dear ABC thank you for your email.
If you have any further query please contact us.

Thanks & Regards

John

Services abc company”,”Null”,”1”,”John”

“789”,”0”,”1”,2012-09-01 11:38:00”,”Dear XYZ thank you for “your” email.
If you have any further query please contact us.

Thanks & Regards,

Max

Services department abc company”,”Null”,”1”,”Max”
```

Comment: Rest of the commas are removed with this command also but extra comma after / Thanks & Regards, / in both the records are not removed. Pls suggest any other solution for this